# Error while updating, I need to install libimobiledevice-utils for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to install `libimobiledevice-utils` for Ubuntu 16.04 . So I need to `sudo apt-get update` but when I run that command I get this error in the output:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
```

Comment: Looks like a networking error. Does your internet connection work alright? What's the output of `ping6 -c4 ph.archive.ubuntu.com`, `ping -c4 ph.archive.ubuntu.com`, and `ping6 -c4 archive.ubuntu.com`? I can't connect to that server either because it rejects all HTTP connections but I can still reach it via ping. You could try a different package repository mirror in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not connected to internet/that repo is not available at the moment. You can try to change the mirror in your sources (e.g. use cz.archive.ubuntu.com )